# How to take difference between variable and lag determined by month date per group?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Essentially, I have a dataset with variables indicating group, date and value of variable. I need to take the difference between the value and the end-of-previous year value per group. Since the data is balanced, I was trying to do that with `dplyr::lag`, inserting the lag given the month of the observation:

```
x <- x %>% group_by(g) %>% mutate(y = v - lag(v, n=month(d))
```

This, however, does not work.

The results should be:

Mock dataset:

```
x <- data.frame('g'=c('B','B','B','C','A','A','A','A','A','A'),'d'=c('2018-11-30', '2018-12-31','2019-01-31','2019-12-31','2016-12-31','2017-11-30','2017-12-31','2018-12-31','2019-01-31','2019-02-28'),'v'=c(300,200,250,100,400,150,200,500,400,500))
```

Desired variable:

```
y <- c(NA,NA,-50,NA,NA,-250,-200,300,-100,0)
```

New dataset:

```
cbind(x,y)
```

Comment: In your mock dataset there is only 1 group: A and there are 2 years: 2018 & 2019, then 2018-12-31 would be the only end-of-previous year per group. I assume there are not 3 consecutive years per group (otherwise there would be 2 end-of-previous year per group). Then you may 1) extract the `year component of the date - 1` to get the previous year, and 2) use `max()` to get the end of a year.

Comment: Apologies, I will make the mock dataset more comprehensive. Indeed, that's what I aim to do. Nevertheless, in a dplyr pipe how can one take the value of the same group with year = year-1 and maximum month? In other words, create a variable which is y = x - x[year==year-1 & month=max(month of that year)]?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot get the values of your desired variable (NA, NA, -50, NA, 500, 100, 0). If the input is data.frame('g'=c('B','B','B','C','A','A','A'),'d'=c('2018-11-30', '2018-12-31','2019-01-31','2017-12-31','2018-12-31','2019-01-31','2019-02-28'),'v'=c(300,200,250,400,500,400,500)), my expected output y is: (NA, NA, 50, NA, NA, -100, 0).

Comment: Indeed, my mistake (in a latter stage I will want the end-of-year not to retrieve NAs but the value itself, though that can easily be done with an ifelse clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to create an auxiliary variable ('eoy') to indicate the row of the corresponding end-of-year per group for each row. It requires a loop and is inefficient but facilitates the remaining computations that will depend on this. The desired computation would become:

mutate('y'= x - x[eoy])

Answer (score 0):

An idea via `dplyr` can be to look for the last day, get the index and use that to subtract and then convert to NAs, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
 group_by(g) %>% 
 mutate(new = which(sub('^[0-9]+-([0-9]+-[0-9]+)$', '\\1', d) == '12-31'), 
        y = v - v[new], 
        y = replace(y, row_number() <= new, NA)) %>% 
 select(-new)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 4
> # Groups:   g [3]
>   g     d              v     y
>   <fct> <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 B     2018-11-30   300    NA
> 2 B     2018-12-31   200    NA
> 3 B     2019-01-31   250    50
> 4 C     2017-12-31   400    NA
> 5 A     2018-12-31   500    NA
> 6 A     2019-01-31   400  -100
> 7 A     2019-02-28   500     0
> ```

Comment: It does not work because my dataset has more than two years per group. How could I adjust the parsing so that it looks for the values which have year = year-1 and '12-31' as in this approach? I am not familiar with regular expressions

Comment: This is an important detail to leave out. Please update your dataset and expected output in your question

Comment: Your approach is exactly what I want, but I would want new to refer to %y-1+'-12-31'

Comment: Added it in the dataset